# How to call IntentService with multiple actions from MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-activity, intentservice

I have to run code on Android 8 or higher.

Presently I have code for IntentService as follows :

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

    // TODO: Rename actions, choose action names that describe tasks that this
    // IntentService can perform, e.g. ACTION_FETCH_NEW_ITEMS
    private static final String ACTION_FOO = "com.example.applocker1.action.FOO";
    private static final String ACTION_BAZ = "com.example.applocker1.action.BAZ";

    // TODO: Rename parameters
    private static final String EXTRA_PARAM1 = "com.example.applocker1.extra.PARAM1";
    private static final String EXTRA_PARAM2 = "com.example.applocker1.extra.PARAM2";

    public MyIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService");
    }

    /**
     * Starts this service to perform action Foo with the given parameters. If
     * the service is already performing a task this action will be queued.
     *
     * @see IntentService
     */
    // TODO: Customize helper method
    public static void startActionFoo(Context context, String param1, String param2) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_FOO);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM1, param1);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM2, param2);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Starts this service to perform action Baz with the given parameters. If
     * the service is already performing a task this action will be queued.
     *
     * @see IntentService
     */
    // TODO: Customize helper method
    public static void startActionBaz(Context context, String param1, String param2) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_BAZ);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM1, param1);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM2, param2);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_FOO.equals(action)) {
                final String param1 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PARAM1);
                final String param2 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PARAM2);
                handleActionFoo(param1, param2);
            } else if (ACTION_BAZ.equals(action)) {
                final String param1 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PARAM1);
                final String param2 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PARAM2);
                handleActionBaz(param1, param2);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle action Foo in the provided background thread with the provided
     * parameters.
     */
    private void handleActionFoo(String param1, String param2) {
        // TODO: Handle action Foo
        Log.i("In Service : ", "Action Foo");
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    /**
     * Handle action Baz in the provided background thread with the provided
     * parameters.
     */
    private void handleActionBaz(String param1, String param2) {
        // TODO: Handle action Baz
        Log.i("In Service : ", "Action Baz");
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

How can I actions ACTION_FOO and ACTION_BAZ from my main activity?

Comment: Whats the issue with this code ?

Comment: I want to call IntentService actions from my activity. But the static action variables are defined inside IntentService class. I need the code for how to call it from MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

To start action FOO in `MainActivity` you do this:

```
MyIntentService.startActionFoo(this, param1, param2);
```

To start action BAZ in `MainActivity` you do this:

```
MyIntentService.startActionBaz(this, param1, param2);
```